# Two instances of DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, razor

I have defined two field properties in the model : public bool? Afield { get; set; }, public bool? Bfield { get; set; }.
In my view I used Razor to used dropdownlistfor to defined possible values for Afield and Bfield. The question is how I can display some values in Bfield when certain value is chosen in Afield dropdownlist:
For example: If Afield is A, then Bfield will only display and allow to choose 1,2,3 for possible options. When Afield is B,then Bfield will only display and allow 3,4...
Code in the view:
Afield:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Afield, new[] {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "A",
                Value = bool.TrueString},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "B",
                Value = bool.TrueString},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "C",
                Value = bool.TrueString}
        }, "Choose Afield")
```

Bfield

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Bfield, new[] {
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "1",
                Value = bool.TrueString},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "2",
                Value = bool.TrueString},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "3",
                Value = bool.TrueString}
        }, "Choose Bfield")
```

etc.

If it needs to be handled any other way, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax for this kind of behaviour.

Check this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/